# Is there an alternative for "set!" on Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket, counting

Was wondering if there's an alternative for using set! in scheme/racket.
Working on assignments and we're not allowed to use set!

For one of my functions I have an incrementer

```
(set! count (+ count 1))
```

Was wondering how I would change this so that it won't make use of set!

Comment: If your 'function' maintains internal state then it's not a function, it's a procedure: a function is *defined* such that `(f x)` is dependent only on `x`.  Probably the intention is that you learn to write programs which are functional.

Comment: Almost always, the alternative is to recurse - in particular when there are lists around. Free books: [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html); [HtDP](http://www.htdp.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the reason you're not allowed to use `set!` is that you're being asked to solve problems in a functional way, rather than an imperative way. Let me illustrate with two different functions that both determine the length of a list:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(define count 0)
(define (imperative-length l)
  (cond [(empty? l) count]
        [else (set! count (+ 1 count))
              (imperative-length (rest l))]))

(check-equal? (imperative-length '(4 3 2 1)) 4)


(define (functional-length l)
  (cond [(empty? l) 0]
        [else (+ 1 (functional-length (rest l)))]))


(check-equal? (functional-length '(4 3 2 1)) 4)


;; what happens if we try calling imperative-length again?


(check-equal? (imperative-length '(4 3 2 1)) 4)

;; oh no!

;; what happens if we try calling functional-length again?

(check-equal? (functional-length '(4 3 2 1)) 4)

;; yep, works fine.
```

Both of these functions work fine, but the functional one can be called repeatedly. But! But! you might say, I just need to remember to set the counter back to zero, or to put the binding of `count` inside the function. This is true, but in general, functional solutions don't require the programmer to worry about this kind of interaction at all.

So, what does this mean for you? It probably means that you need to pass the `count` along as another argument. Just a guess.

Comment: we could also say  that there's *no*  alternative to `set!` where `set!` is the only way to do the job (i.e. mutate a  hidden binding in a closure, with a network of communicating objects or something). :)

Answer (score 1):

`set!` is never needed. Imagine you have this program:

```
(define (count lst)
  (define num 0)
  (define (helper lst)
    (when (not (null? lst))
      (set! num (+ num 1))
      (helper (cdr lst))))
  (helper lst)
  num)
```

This is almost Fortran with lisp syntax. How would this be done witout `set!`. One way is by using boxes:

```
(define (count lst)
  (define num (list 0))
  (define (helper lst)
    (when (not (null? lst))
      (set-car! num (+ (car num) 1))
      (helper (cdr lst))))
  (helper lst)
  (car num))
```

As explained in the SICP videos when you introduce one mutation you sort of can use that to do all types of mutation. As trivia  this is a transformation that often is done by Scheme compilers so in many cases the implementations base language has `set-car!` and not `set!`. How about doing it without mutation? The trick is to shadow the binding:

```
(define (count lst)
  (define (helper num lst)
    (if (not (null? lst))
        (helper (+ num 1) (cdr lst))
        num))
  (helper 0 lst))
```

This actually got simpler. Imagine you only need to update some of the variables, then you just recurse with the same ones in the other places.